# jquery hasClass in for loop is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a simple script that checks if a list item has a specific class or not.

But I am always getting `"parkingSlots[i].hasClass is not a function"`

I read the docs of jquery.hasClass and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
    const inputIsOpen = document.getElementById("isOpen");
const inputWrapperOpen = $(".checkboxWrap")[0];

$(".checkboxWrap").click(function() {

    let parkingSlots = $(".location-list--item");
    console.log("CheckFilter aufgerufen");

    if(inputIsOpen.checked == true) {
        console.log("if")
        for(let i = 0; i < parkingSlots.length; i++) {
            if(parkingSlots[i].hasClass("list-Parkhaus-open")) {
                console.log("if2")
                
            } else {
                parkingSlots[i].css("display", "none");
                console.log("else2")
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("else");
    }
})
```

Comment: Alternative: `parkingSlots.eq(i).hasClass` to use jquery objects

Answer (score 4):

Because `parkingSlots[i]` gives you JS object, not jQuery object.

Do `$(parkingSlots[i]).hasClass`

---

Or use `.each`:

```js
parkingSlots.each(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass("list-Parkhaus-open")) {
        console.log("if2")
                
    } else {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
        console.log("else2")
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(parkingSlots[i])` *might* be better as `parkingSlots.eq(i)` to reduce the amount of switching between dom/jquery